# Resusing a panel for multiple documents in a document based application

Tags: objective-c, nspanel

I'm creating a Document-Based Applications and I'd like to use a single NSPanel that is reused across multiple open documents.

I should be able to change settings in the NSPanel for the first open document and then click on another open document. When I click on the second open document the NSPanel should update to show the settings for the active document.

What would be the proper way to structure this setup?